# Monero GUI Ledger not fully syncing

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, cold-storage, wallet-recovery, ledger, hardware

I have been struggling to get my monero wallet to fully sync with my ledger

I have tried feather wallet and it simply does not sync

The official monero GUI wallet syncs to about 95% but then seems to get stuck and not sync any further

I really cannot figure this out.

what am i missing?